# Chrome extension won't reopen once closed Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The Chrome extension I've made in Javascript won't reopen once the extension popup is closed.

manifest.js:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "  #######",
  "description": "Tracker .",
  "version": "0.7",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
     "matches": ["file:///*"],
     "js":      ["js/Content-script.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/trace.png",
    "default_title": "Trace"
  }
}
```

The extension when first loaded to chrome, opens and works perfectly. But if the popup is closed and I try to reopen the extension from the top right extensions list, it doesn't open.

Is there any initialization script I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
"default_popup": "html/popup.html"
```

to the browser_action section (assumes a html directory, as you have a js dir). That's assuming your reference to popup refers to a popup.html you have in your extension?

The fact that it appears at all suggests you might be opening it programatically from the background script - as you didn't provide any other code. Hopefully this will get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Turns out the issue was the local storage, I was setting an initialization variable in the local storage which was not accessible to the newer Tab. Making a few Changes resolved the issue.